# python tkinter treeview right click (Button-3) event to select item in treeview

Tags: python, treeview, tkinter

Using Python 3.2 and tkinter. How do you make the Button-3 (right click) select the item in a Treeview widget that the mouse cursor is hovering over? I basically want the Button-3 event to select the item in the same way as the current single left click does.

Comment: I have managed to figure it out. Using the identify_row method of the Treeview and passing the y coordinate to the method it returns the current iid of the item in the row the mouse is hovering over.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Feel free to post that as a solution if you're able.  That way, others will be able to see how to accomplish this more easily.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You half answered your own question. Just coded and tested my code, so thought no harm in posting my solution snippet here.

```
def init(self):
    """initialise dialog"""
    # Button-3 is right click on windows
    self.tree.bind("<Button-3>", self.popup)

def popup(self, event):
    """action in event of button 3 on tree view"""
    # select row under mouse
    iid = self.tree.identify_row(event.y)
    if iid:
        # mouse pointer over item
        self.tree.selection_set(iid)
        self.contextMenu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)            
    else:
        # mouse pointer not over item
        # occurs when items do not fill frame
        # no action required
        pass
```

Comment: Similar approach can be used to close an item by clicking the center button (click with the mouse wheel) to close an item. Do it by binding `<Button-2>` in Windows.